# disable RDP auto-logout on Windows Server 2008

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I seem to have a problem with my server logging out the user 1 hour after the RDP session has closed. I want the user to always stay logged in so I can have an application running 24/7. I've tried a few different things that I saw online:

1) I've changed my Administrator User's "session" tab settings to have no time limits:

*Edit* Tried to post image, but I don't have enough rep.

2) I've looked at my local policy settings (both computer and user) for session time limits. Everything is set to Unassigned, and it says in the policy description that if unassigned the default is unlimited session time:

*Edit* Tried to post image, but I don't have enough rep.

3) In the windows system event log I always see the 7002 winlogon event ("User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program") always around 1 hour after I've closed out of the Remote session. So I tried turning off the customer experience improvment program using the steps outlined in this post:

[User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0439e00b-f44a-40ac-999c-e574cb575ba9/user-logoff-notification-for-customer-experience-improvement-program?forum=w7itprogeneral)

So far nothing has worked, it still continues to log the user off 1 hour after closing out of the remote session, and the application closes when the user is logged out. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/99258/remote-desktop-sessions-unwanted-automatic-log-off-after-period-of-time

Comment: I tried DanBig's answer already. its my 1)

ManiacZX, and Subiah R Nagarajan's answers are reffering to  what I tried in 2)

None of these answers worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking into this in the future I was able to fix it by modifying a few registry settings.

Theres a short tutorial here, that worked for me (Option 2):
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/118889-remote-desktop-set-time-limit-idle-sessions.html